# Apply macro to every `n`-th line

Tags: macro

I would like to apply macro `a` to a set of lines. For consecutive lines, this can be done by

```
:5,10norm! @a
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390174/in-vim-how-do-i-apply-a-macro-to-a-set-of-lines).

How to do it for every `n`-th line from my current cursor position?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about writing a 2nd macro that moves down n lines and then executes @a? Using a mark you can easily jump back to your original position.

E.g., having defined your macro in register a, press `qb` to record in register b, press `5j` to go to line 6, press `@a` to execute a and then `q` to quit recording. Using `9@b` will then execute macro a on every 5th line, i.e. lines 11, 16, 21,..., up to line 51. Since `j` will fail at the end of the file, simpy use `1000@b` for the whole file... adjust numbers as needed.

Comment: I was going to write an answer using a recursive macro (with basically the same logic), but this is better in every way so I'll just +1 this instead

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

1. record current line number and `n` in some variables:

   ```
   :let c=line('.')
   :let n=2
   ```
2. conditionally run the macro from your `a` register on every `n`-th line *after* the cursor:

   ```
   :g/^/if line('.') > c &&  (line('.') - c) % n == 0 | norm! @a
   ```

I also believe that it would be easier to alter the macro instead (to jump `n` lines below as its first or last operation).